# API Platform GraphQL Security in Relationships

Tags: symfony, security, graphql, entity-relationship, api-platform.com

My problem is the security implementation of the entities when consumed through GraphQL, the queries are perfect, they return the necessary data, but the problem occurs when a query is generated and the many-to-one relationship is limited to having a role "ROLE_ADMIN", the query returns the data even when the user has the role "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"

**How to add the security layer so that data from protected relationships cannot be obtained?**

> The product query must be seen without any role.

*Additional Information*

GraphQL Query User Admin

```
query {
    userAdmin(id: "api/user_admins/1") {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

GraphQL Query User Admin Result OK

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Sorry, but you don't have access",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "graphql"
      }
  ]
}
```

GraphQL Query Product

```
query {
    products {
        edges {
            node {
                name
                price
                user {
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GraphQL Query Product Result **FAILED**

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "GERLACH-HAAG",
            "price": "175",
            "user": {
              "name": "Sidney Deane" /** this information should not be seen **/
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Entity Product Configuration

```
<?php

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     graphql={
 *          "item_query",
 *          "collection_query",
 *          "delete"={ "security" = "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')" },
 *          "create"={ "security" = "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')" },
 *          "update"={ "security" = "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')" }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="TBL_PRODUCTS")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", name="ID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, name="NAME")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserAdmin")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="USER", referencedColumnName="ID")
     */
    private $user;
```

Entity User Admin Configuration

```
<?php

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     graphql={
 *          "item_query"={ "security" = "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')" },
 *          "collection_query"={ "security" = "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')" },
 *          "delete"={ "security" = "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')" },
 *          "create"={ "security" = "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')" },
 *          "update"={ "security" = "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')" }
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="TBL_USERS_ADMIN")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserAdminRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class UserAdmin implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", name="ID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, name="USERNAME")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, name="PASSWORD")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, name="NAME")
     */
    private $name;
```

**Please help !!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `security` attribute allows to define roles or permissions necessary to execute a given query. However, it doesn't define which relation available trough this query the user can access. To do so, you can use [dynamic serialization groups](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/graphql/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically).

Basically, mark the properties requiring a special role to be returned in the response with a specific serialization group, such as `@Groups("admin")`, then create a dynamic serialization context builder to add the special group if the connected user has this special role:

```
<?php

namespace App\Serializer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\GraphQl\Serializer\SerializerContextBuilderInterface;
use App\Entity\Book;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

final class BookContextBuilder implements SerializerContextBuilderInterface
{
    private $decorated;
    private $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(SerializerContextBuilderInterface $decorated, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }

    public function create(?string $resourceClass, string $operationName, array $resolverContext, bool $normalization): array
    {
        $context = $this->decorated->create($resourceClass, $operationName, $resolverContext, $normalization);
        $resourceClass = $context['resource_class'] ?? null;

        if ($resourceClass === Book::class && isset($context['groups']) && $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') && false === $normalization) {
            $context['groups'][] = 'admin';
        }

        return $context;
    }
}
```

In the master version (API Platform 2.6), [the `security` attribute is now also available for properties](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/3503). Unfortunately, this feature is currently available only in the REST subsystem, but we will be very pleased to merge a Pull Request adding support for this attribute to the GraphQL subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using exclusion policies on your entities. You will need to use the JMS Serializer Bundle

Example:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="TBL_PRODUCTS")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */

class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserAdmin")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="USER", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"ROLE_ADMIN"}) // only users with ROLE_ADMIN will see this
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $user;
    
    /**
     * ...
     * @Serializer\Groups({"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"}) // only users with ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN will see this
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $superSecretData;

    ...
}
```

This wil expose the `$user` property only when the user has the ROLE_ADMIN.
In your controller/service where you expose your data, you should add the users role to the serialization context:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

...


        $entities = $repository->findAll();

        $responseData = $this->serializer->serialize(
            $entities,
            'json',
            SerializationContext::create()
                ->setGroups(['ROLE_USER']) // Add all roles you want
        );

        $response = new Response(
            $responseData,
            Response::HTTP_OK
        );

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
```

This way you should be able to exclude or expose some properties based on the users' role.